# How can i capture https respond via fiddlercore?

Tags: c#, wpf, https, fiddlercore

I have download fiddlercore DEMO,and i try to use it in my application whitch was depends on WPF,then i hava a question that in my application i can't capture https responds resources? 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7Pk.png)

my code just under below:

```
    using Fiddler;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace operateToolWPF.Utils
{
    public class MyFiddler
    {
        static Proxy oSecureEndpoint;
        static string sSecureEndpointHostname = "localhost";
        static int iSecureEndpointPort = 7777;
        public List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions { get; set; }


        public  void DoQuit()
        {
            if (null != oSecureEndpoint) oSecureEndpoint.Dispose();
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
            //Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        private  string CalcResponseSize(Session oS)
        {
            if (null == oS.oResponse) return String.Empty;
            var cBytesOut = 0;

            if (null != oS.responseBodyBytes) cBytesOut += oS.responseBodyBytes.Length;
            if ((null != oS.oResponse) && (null != oS.oResponse.headers)) cBytesOut +=
               oS.oResponse.headers.ByteCount();
            return cBytesOut.ToString();
        }

        public  void WriteSessionList(List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions)
        {
            ConsoleColor oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Session list contains...");
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions);
                foreach (Session oS in oAllSessions)
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}　{3} {4}  {5}  {6}\n", oS.id, oS.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod, oS.fullUrl, oS.responseCode, oS.oResponse.MIMEType, (oS.Timers.ClientBeginResponse - oS.Timers.ClientBeginRequest), CalcResponseSize(oS)));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
        }


        public void DoFiddler()
        {
            oAllSessions = new List<Fiddler.Session>();
            //if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
            //{
            //    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
            //    {
            //        throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
            //    }
            //}

            //if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
            //{
            //    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.trustRootCert())
            //    {
            //        throw new Exception("Unable to install FiddlerCore's cert.");
            //    }
            //}

            #region AttachEventListeners
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.OnNotification += delegate(object sender, NotificationEventArgs oNEA) { 
                Console.WriteLine("** NotifyUser: " + oNEA.NotifyString); 
            };
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Log.OnLogString += delegate(object sender, LogEventArgs oLEA) { 
                Console.WriteLine("** LogString: " + oLEA.LogString); 
            };

            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest");
                oS.bBufferResponse = true;
                Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions); 
                oAllSessions.Add(oS);
                //Console.Write(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}　{3} {4}  {5}  {6}\n", oS.id, oS.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod, oS.fullUrl, oS.responseCode, oS.oResponse.MIMEType, (oS.Timers.ClientBeginResponse - oS.Timers.ClientBeginRequest), CalcResponseSize(oS)));
                Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);
                oS["X-AutoAuth"] = "(default)";
                if ((oS.oRequest.pipeClient.LocalPort == iSecureEndpointPort) && (oS.hostname == sSecureEndpointHostname))
                {
                    oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
                    oS.oResponse.headers.SetStatus(200, "Ok");
                    oS.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
                    oS.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";
                    oS.utilSetResponseBody("<html><body>Request for httpS://" + sSecureEndpointHostname + ":" + iSecureEndpointPort.ToString() + " received. Your request was:<br /><plaintext>" + oS.oRequest.headers.ToString());
                }
            };

            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete");
                //Console.Title = ("Session list contains: " + oAllSessions.Count.ToString() + " sessions");
                //DoQuit();
            };

            // Tell the system console to handle CTRL+C by calling our method that
            // gracefully shuts down the FiddlerCore.
            //
            // Note, this doesn't handle the case where the user closes the window with the close button.
            // See http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx for info on that...
            //
            #endregion AttachEventListeners
            string sSAZInfo = "NoSAZ";
#if SAZ_SUPPORT
            sSAZInfo = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Ionic.Zip.ZipFile)).FullName;

            DNZSAZProvider.fnObtainPwd = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the password (or just hit Enter to cancel):");
                string sResult = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                return sResult;
            };

            FiddlerApplication.oSAZProvider = new DNZSAZProvider();
#endif

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Starting {0} ({1})...", Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.GetVersionString(), sSAZInfo));
            Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.network.streaming.abortifclientaborts", true);

            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
            int iPort = 8877;
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(iPort, oFCSF);
            FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created endpoint listening on port {0}", iPort);

            FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Starting with settings: [{0}]", oFCSF);
            FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Gateway: {0}", CONFIG.UpstreamGateway.ToString());

            oSecureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(iSecureEndpointPort, true, sSecureEndpointHostname);
            if (null != oSecureEndpoint)
            {
                FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created secure endpoint listening on port {0}, using a HTTPS certificate for '{1}'", iSecureEndpointPort, sSecureEndpointHostname);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

who can help me ?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Hope this solve all u vr Problem in this Demo application he has Clearly explained how to track the HTTP and HTTPS request.. For HTTP You can directly listen to the AfterSessionComplete event but for HTTPS you need to install the Fiddler core certificate this 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jul/29/using-fiddlercore-to-capture-http-requests-with-net

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your advance was useful to me! Even though it's so long that i can't understand lot!

Comment: if you have any doubt in fiddler core you can ask...!! or if you find any thing difficult.

Comment: I have a new question.How could i hide the window which one notice to install certificate(DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot)?It's about the user experience。Thanks!

Comment: u can't avoid the DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot window one thing you can do is that you can maintain the certificate and its key locally in a file and when ever you restart the service just load the key and the certificate from it so that the window will not popup .. just look how can you save the key and certificate.

Comment: @zhangmike has it worked for you if its worked then mark it as answer and do a upvote so that it will be helpful for other users

Comment: I have no idea about how to operate it.I need to think about it.Thank you!@Ravi Kanth